# Unlocking the dungeon door

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

Any feedback is welcome. I'm new to puzzling in general so please let me know how long it took you to come up with your answer and what your thoughts were. I have tough skin.

**Hint**

> There's two parts here, If you're struggling then solve it bit by bit.

**Hint 2**

> There should be 10 symbols at the top, three are missing. The section to the right is not independent from the others.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer appears to be:

> Water Drop, Rewind Symbol

Because if we:

> Assign each symbol a value from 0 - 9 going left to right

The doors read:

> X4, Y2, 1X, __, since the doors must have some sequence to make it solvable, and given the values of the gaps in the list above, it seems likely that this should read: 
>  64, 32, 16 
>  Clearly halving each time.

Meaning the final door should read

> 08, translating to Water Drop, Rewind

Comment: Correct! I'm thrilled someone was able to figure this out, I started to think maybe it was too obscure. The first hint was designed to give you confidence in the pattern you discovered if you're familiar with computers.

Comment: What indication for numbering was there? I’m curious how that was identified?

Comment: @Adib, In general, 10 symbols. However from leigero's comment on your answer the symbols were just place holders, so I replaced them with placeholders where it would be easier to spot a pattern.
Rot13(Gur qbbe ahzoref ubjrire, abgvpvat gur svefg qbbe unq n "4" naq gur frpbaq n "2" yrnq gb gelvat n ahzore juvpu yrnqf gb 2 zbq 10)

Answer (score 4):

I don't get it yet, but this is my first attempt on this puzzle.

> Code is based on Webdings and Wingdings. Therefore, the top part is saying: 
>
>
>  SQR [CRACK/MISSING?] PU [SPACE][SPACE] 7A

Door 1

> R (C/P/O?)

Door 2

> LR

Door 3

> QR

Door 4

> I believe the hint is saying something about squares? So I'm trying to see if it's R or some other value

Comment: Not a bad attempt! I should tell you, though, that my use of Wingdings was purely to get symbols more quickly and the font (and the letters represented as such) are irrelevant. The idea was to draw symbols and I, perhaps, should have invented my own.

Comment: Ah! Well then, time to revisit the whiteboard

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer but an initial thought.

I hope that the answer includes

> Magic Eye

Because then you could

> Make the 4 doors into 5 to match the 10 symbols up top with the pattern involving superposition of door symbols on top of each other.

Comment: Great out of the box thinking!

Answer (score 0):

This is only a wild guess, but here is the perspective of a non-god in puzzles.

> The Symbols missing are the water and tilted-square, which belong to the most right door i think.
>  The most right symbols probably mean that, whatever door the left symbols mention, 2 doors to the left of that is the right door.
>  The Symbols on the left go from the right door to the left and then to the right door again, so I think that the *correct door is the second from the left*.
>  There is no sign that a symbol was supposed to be in the crack at the symbols, because the black thing isn't big enough to cover an entire symbol, but there is no sign of a symbol beneath it. My guess would be that it's just distraction.

Simple, but I hope i explained it correctly

Comment: Also, welcome to puzzling! Sorry for the late welcome, but take the [tour](/tour) to earn your first badge.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the door with missing symbols is

> A water and filled circle
>  [image: Solution]

We have the [pattern](/questions/tagged/pattern) tag.

---

Looking from the top right symbol, we have a hint:

> I interpret this as "Backwards correct"

Looking from the leftmost door (X and square) and the symbols in the top, we can see

> Something's common: **the square** in the symbols and the door.

The next door has a symbol of filled circle and a sun-like symbol. Seeing this and the top one again,

> **The sun-like symbol is common**.

Continuing,

> The airport symbol is common in the right door and the symbols. This means our next pattern will be a **water symbol.**

What about the cross and the filled circle?

> That's obvious: Cross in left, filled in left, cross in right, and our next pattern should be **filled in right.**

Yet I don't know how will the [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher) tag will work for this one.